# nginx stopped serving static folder for django app by using WSL

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL to run nginx to serve django app on "d" partition, yesterday it worked just fine, today stopped working correctly.
this is my conf file:

```
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8000; 
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name xxx.xxx.x.xxx; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

# Django static

    location /static {
        alias /mnt/d/backend/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

server and domain name are the same as allowed host in settings.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")]
```

I am not sure if I am referring to the right path for the static files.
as they are in different location, I am little confused about using virtual environment, wsl at the same time.

```
(venv) root@DESKTOP-XXXXXX:/mnt/d/backend
```

the problem is that the server doesn't load the static files.

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG=False`? Django serves static files when `DEBUG=True`. Maybe you were not serving your static files over nginx. This would tell you where the problem is.

Comment: your STATIC_ROOT is where `manage.py collectstatic` puts your static files, which is the location where nginx will go get them. So it should be `/mnt/d/backend/static/`, not inside of BASE_DIR.

Comment: exactly this what I did

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still not working. maybe there is another thing I need to check

Comment: if you go into the WSL shell and do `ls /mnt/d/backend/static` can you see your static files? If not you need to change that to point to where they actually are.

Comment: the path is right, all files exist. thank you guys for trying to help me with this issue.

Comment: I tried using root instead of alias, still the same result. I am also using drf is it make a difference?

Comment: can you try `location /static/ { alias /mnt/d/backend/static/; }` with the trailing /?

Comment: and also you should take a look at your nginx log files (in /var/log/nginx) to see if they contain more information about the problem. In your browser, do you see a 404 error? Or is it another error? An issue could be that the user you're running nginx with doesn't have access to the files in /mnt/d/backend/static.

Comment: I am getting 404 errors:

Comment: Not Found: /static/rest_framework/js/default.js

Comment: and in the nginx log? it should tell you which file path it tried to fetch.

Comment: "/usr/share/nginx/html/admin" ,
Usr/share is the location it is expecting to find the static file in.

Comment: the static files is for admin page and drf, according to this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/772465/nginx-serving-static-files)`answer`, I should change all the linking inside templates, is it right?